# Cakephp 3: belongsToMany contain or matching condition?

Tags: cakephp-3.x

Piece of my database looks like [database part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eMdI.jpg)

Categories use tree behavior.

How can i get a manufacturer's (Producers) Products for current Category? 
I tried contain and matching, but i received duplicated data or Producers names without related Products.

EDIT:

```
$query = $this->Producers->find()->matching('Products.Categories',
    function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Categories.id' => 18]); 
    }
);
```

Results:

```
Producent: Canon
-------------------------------------------
| ID | Name        | Barcode              |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | EOS 1000D   |                      |
-------------------------------------------
| 18 | Camera      |                      |
-------------------------------------------
| 23 | 18          |                      |
-------------------------------------------
```

First row (id = 1) it's what i need.
Now i have to remove from results:
second row (id = 18) this is Category id from table Categories, 
thrid row (id = 23) - from Products_Categories table.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I have to display Products by Producers in current Category ie:

category: camera

Producer Canon:
- EOS 1000D
- Powershot

Producer: Nikon
- product D5
- product: D700

Comment: What @arilia was asking for is some example code of your failed attempts (ideally with additional info, like whether there may be producers that do not have any products associated yet). Generally matching is the way to go.

Comment: My bad, i understood differently - like too deep association. 
OK, that's my actually results, now i'm closer.

`
$query = $this->Producers->find()->matching(
   'Products.Categories', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Categories.id' => 18]);
   }
`
ofcourse returns everything with categories.id = 18, like data from Category and Products_Categories.

Comment: add code to your question post, not here.

Comment: Thnx @Salines, i still learn posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. There is working query:

```
$query = $this->Producers->find()
        ->select(['Producers.id','Producers.name', 'Products.id',   'Products.name'])
        ->matching(
            'Products.Categories', function ($q) use ($categoryId){
                return $q->where(['Categories.id' => $categoryId]);
            }
        );
```